# Drop-Down Menu - http://www.kiaglobal.com/mu/en/main/ - jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am looking to re-create the drop-down menu located at: http://www.kiaglobal.com/mu/en/main/ and am not sure where to start. The drop-down activates when you roll-over the top left three links. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I really do not know how much help you need.

But if you know a little jQuery I just need to tell you that you can use `.slideDown()` and `.slideUp()`

Read more about it here:
http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/

If you need any other help, let me know.

Comment: Ok, here is where i'm stuck...

I am using jquery .animate and the drop down is working reasonably well.  I just run into the problem of when the menu is down, rolling over the button again causes the menu to animate down again.  If I could disable the .animate function while the menu is open I should be all set.  Any thoughts?

Comment: You could set a var to detect if it is down or up? or code a solution that detects it.

Comment: I tried that with no luck.  I just set a simple int variable outside the .animate function to 0 and added a if var = 0 run the .animate function.  In the function I change the var to 1.  Alert popups show me the var is 1 when I roll over the button and the menu is open as it should, but the .animate funciton still triggers even though its within a if var = 0.

Comment: I need to have a look at the code I think. I have done something like this myself so it should be no problem when I see it.

Comment: Sure.. please have a look here... [link](http://www.kia.ca/temp/layout/index.html)

Comment: Does not seem to animate at all here? Am I doing something wrong? What file do I need to look in?

Comment: Strange, here is what I am working with... <script> $("div.nav").mouseover(function(){ $("div.menu").animate({"top": "+=400px"}, "slow"); }); $("div.menu").mouseout(function(){ $("div.menu").animate({"top": "-=400px"}, "slow"); }); </script>'

Sorry, new to this, can't seem to get the code link thing to work..

Answer (score 0):

First use jQuery

If you hover over an element it slide down right?

You need an element for example: `$("div#navigation a")`

Than you need to add an hover event because it appears when you hover over it: 
`$("div#navigation a").mouseover(function() {});`

So you hover over it but nothing happens :(
Thats why you need to slide down a div which you had need to create before.
`<div class="dropdown">For Navigation point one</div><div class="dropdown">For Navigation point two</div>`

You need `.eq($(this).index())` because otherwise it won't know which div it should slide down

```
$("div#navigation a").mouseover(function() {
    /* move to a postion (change it if you want it in another postion) */
    $("div.dropdown").eq($(this).index()).offset({top: ($(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight()), left: $(this).offset().left});
    /* slide down the div */
    $("div.dropdown").eq($(this).index()).slideDown(/* time in milliseconds if you want another time than standard */);
});
```

This is opening but you need to close it too. But that is easy. I hope you got it.
Ohh yes one last hint: `$("div.dropdown").slideUp(/* time in milliseconds if you want another time than standard */);`

Comment: Thank you for the response!  This works great but for some reason the very 1st time I rollover it doesn't actually slide down, it just appears down.  It works great after that though.